# Chi squared test - free parameters

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared

I know that for a Chi squared test where we have $\Theta_0$ free parameters under the null hypothesis $H_0$ and $\Theta_1$ free parameters under the alternative hypothesis $H_1$, that 
$$2\log\Lambda \sim \chi_{\Theta_1 - \Theta_0}$$
It is also true that for $m>n$ that $\chi_m^{-1}(\alpha) > \chi_n^{-1}(\alpha)$.
Thus, when $\Theta_0$ gets smaller (i.e. when we make our null hypothesis stronger) our rejection level $\chi_{\Theta_1 - \Theta_0}(\alpha)$ become larger.

My question is, why is this the case? I would have assumed that making our null hypothesis stronger would make it more likely that we reject it?

Comment: Is this a confusion about the language? As far as I know a smaller $\Theta_0$ corresponds to a **weaker** hypothesis, as there are fewer parameters being hypothesized. The weaker (less restrictive, looser, lamer, and less impactful) hypothesis would be to hypothesize about almost nothing, with $\Theta_0$ very small.

Comment: But surely if we have to specify fewer variable to define the distribution, we are making a stronger assumption about the underlying distribution? for instance our null hypothesis could have 2 free variables $p_1$ and $p_2$ or we could make the stronger assumption that $p_1 = p_2$, reducing the number of free variables.

Comment: In this example, the hypothesis $\{ p_1 = c_1, p_2 = c_2 \}$ is stronger then your "$p_1 = p_2 = \text{any constant}$".

Comment: I don't understand why that would be the case, I $c_1$ and $c_2$ are both unspecified constants in the above

Comment: By writing $c_1$ and $c_2$ it means they are specified.

Comment: Okay, I would agree that it is stronger, but that is a different example to what I gave

Comment: With $\{ p_1 = c_1, p_2 = c_2 \}$ the free parameters go from the original two (totally free) down to zero $\Theta_0 = 0$ (completely specified), while "$p_1 = p_2 = \text{any constant}$" still leaves one degree of freedom $\Theta_0 = 1$, that "any constant" is free to be any value.

Comment: In that case, the hypothesis with the smaller $\Theta_0$ is stonger which goes against your first point?

Comment: Oh yeah indeed halfway through the comments I made a mistaken of switching to your phrasing/terminology of "free parameter" as I was copying the texts. The context I'm used to working in is that "$\Theta_0$ is the number of parameters specified/hypothesized" so it's actually the opposite/complement to the free parameters (implicit idea is that the "original" freedom is infinite: the distribution could be anything). So this could be a difference of convention in the language.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. My terminology of $\Theta_0$ is the number of free variables yet to be specified. Using this notation I still do not see why my rejection level becomes higher for stronger hypotheses?